# How to make column in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, multiple-columns

[I Want That Date which showing in First Image to print and show like in second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA1Bv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this tutorial 
https://blogs.sap.com/2012/12/14/format-with-multiple-columns-feature-of-the-crystal-report/
 This document gives insight into the format multiple column feature available in the section expert of the details section in the crystal report